# Cannot edit fields of django's formets empty_form in views

Tags: django, forms, view

I'm using empty_forms from Django's BaseFormset in order to dynamically append inline forms to a parent. Works fine for edit/create view.

Now however I need to implement, in essence, a DuplicateView. I'm basically using a CreateView, tweaking it in get_context_data() to populate it with the object to duplicate. Something like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    self.object = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    logger.info(f"ProduitDuplicateView.get_context_data - object id/code: {self.object.pk} {self.object.no_prod}")
    if self.request.POST:
        # code
    else:
        ctx["form"] = ProduitForm(instance=self.object)
        fourprodfrmset = FourProdFormSet(instance=self.object)
        casefrmset = CaseFormSet(instance=self.object)
```

I do need to set the instance to self.object, because I want to populate existing inline forms for the base object to be duplicated with the relevent data. However, that inlineform includes a foreign key to the parent object, which by default is set to the parent object's pk value.  For the form instance, I set it to none like so:

```
    for f in formset:
        try:
            f.initial.pop("fk_produit")
            f.fields["fk_produit"].initial = None
        except KeyError as ex:
            logger.info(f"There was no fk_produit in form.initial for this form of the formset")
```

That works fine for the form instance. However, I also need to do the same with the empty_form - otherwise, when I append the emtpy_form to my inline formset, then it is set to the base object's pk. Which means saving new inline forms this way results in an error (something like the "the inline form's id differs from the parent form's id").

SO I tried setting it this way:

```
for formset in [fourprodfrmset, casefrmset]:
    try:
        formset.empty_form.fields["fk_produit"].initial = None
    except KeyError as ex:
        logger.info(f"Couldn't remove fk_produit initial value in formset empty_form")
```

However, for some reason, it has no effect - if I debug it at the end of the method, formset's emtpy_form field "fk_produit" *still* has its base value (e.g. that of the base object).

So..... How can I modify the empty_form field's value? PReferebly in the View, since that's where I take care of all those shenanigans.

Of course I could do that template-wise I guess, but it would entail more work.... I'd be really more keen on handling that in the view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the crux of the matter is that the question is somewhat misguided - to implement a duplication, there's a better way. See this post on [django forums](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/duplicating-an-object-with-a-form/8571/4) for details.

Essentially, your DuplicateView could inherite from your CreateView (and potentially even use the same template). Then the key bit is this:

```
myformset.management_form.initial["INITIAL_FORMS"] = 0     # otherwise, django saves the loaded ones in-place in the DB instead of creating new fouprods for this one
```

Basically, django treates the INITIAL_FORMS somewhat differently than any forms you dynamically added via ajax when you save them. It tries to update an object in DB with the initial ones, while it creates some for the newer ones. Thus I'm essentially populating the first forms with those from the base object (e.g. duplicating the inline forms), but then I'm telling django with this lines that they are all new forms. So then it saves them as actually instances, referencing the PK of the newly created object as it should

As for the narrow question (in case someone actually needs to do that), there's not good django way to that. empty_form is a mess of accessors & properties that you cannot directly edit. If you really wanted to do that, I guess you'd need to re-write parts of the renderer (so that the final html changes). I wouldn't touch that.

A better solution would be in the template - something like:

```
 {% if field.auto-id=="id_mymodel-__prefix__-fk_fieldname" %}
    <input type="hidden" name="mymodel-__prefix__-fk_fieldname" id="id_mymodel-__prefix__-fk_fieldname">
{% else %}     
    # regular code    
{% endif %}
```

So essentially, find the field that this foreign_key corresponds to, then manually write the html tag, omitting the value="" part.